# What must I do in order to integrate a carousell into Bootstrap page

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap

http://www.bootply.com/106282#

This is the link for carousel. Where must I introduce this code ?

HTML

```
<div class="col-md-12 text-center"><h3>Bootstrap 3 Multiple Slide Carousel</h3></div>
<div class="carousel slide" id="myCarousel">
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="item active">
      <div class="col-xs-2"><a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/500/e499e4/fff&amp;text=1" class="img-responsive"></a></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="col-xs-2"><a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/500/e477e4/fff&amp;text=2" class="img-responsive"></a></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="col-xs-2"><a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/500/eeeeee&amp;text=3" class="img-responsive"></a></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="col-xs-2"><a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/500/f4f4f4&amp;text=4" class="img-responsive"></a></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="col-xs-2"><a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/500/f566f5/333&amp;text=5" class="img-responsive"></a></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="col-xs-2"><a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/500/f477f4/fff&amp;text=6" class="img-responsive"></a></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="col-xs-2"><a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/500/eeeeee&amp;text=7" class="img-responsive"></a></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="col-xs-2"><a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/500/fcfcfc/333&amp;text=8" class="img-responsive"></a></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></i></a>
  <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></i></a>
</div>
```

JS

```
$('#myCarousel').carousel({
  interval: 4000
})

$('.carousel .item').each(function(){
  var next = $(this).next();
  if (!next.length) {
    next = $(this).siblings(':first');
  }
  next.children(':first-child').clone().appendTo($(this));

  for (var i=0;i<4;i++) {
    next=next.next();
    if (!next.length) {
        next = $(this).siblings(':first');
    }

    next.children(':first-child').clone().appendTo($(this));
  }
});
```

Comment: Put it into your page perhaps? Read the docs.

Comment: I did this, but it's not working (aroow that must change photos did not work)

Comment: Then check the console. What errors are you having? Did you include the necessary javascript on the page?

Comment: Where can I see the errors ? The problem is that it is the first time I use Bootstrap, that's why I am asking. that's what I include 
<script src="js/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>

Comment: Console? `F12` to open the debugging tool on Chrome/Firefox/IE, then find and open console.

Comment: Error: Bootstrap's JavaScript requires jQuery 
this is the error, but I still dont know how to fix it

Answer (score 1):

First of all, check that all the files really exist in where your paths point. Just to eliminate 404 errors.

If that doesn't work, you could try using the [migration](http://github.com/jquery/jquery-migrate/#readme) plugin for jQuery.

From the jQuery download page:

> We have created the jQuery Migrate plugin to simplify the transition from older versions of jQuery. The plugin restores deprecated features and behaviors so that older code will still run properly on jQuery 1.9 and later. Use the uncompressed development version to diagnose compatiblity issues, it will generate warnings on the console that you can use to identify and fix problems. Use the compressed production version to simply fix compatibility issues without generating console warnings.